# Elements must have sufficient color contrast issue when Model popup opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, kendo-react-ui

We are using the axe dev tool for the accessibility testing. when we open the model popup( kendo react model with position: absolute), elements behind the popup give insufficient color contrast errors. when I changed the absolute position to sticky I couldn't see any errors. sticky position will not be suitable in my case. please help me to address my issues.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: absolute;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 0px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving the modal element the correct accessibility properties ?

It should have an `role="alertdialog"` or `role="dialog"` and once open you should set `aria-modal="true"`. I am thinking (have not tried it) that your dev tool should pick up that it is a modal and not care about the background elements.

Read:

- [ARIA: alertdialog role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/alertdialog_role)
- [ARIA: dialog role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/dialog_role)
- [aria-modal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-modal)

Comment: I have verified with all of the above solutions, but my issue is not resolved